# how to display data using isingleresult means LINQ to SQL in ASP.net with MVC architechure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i create a one dbml file under model folder.in that one table is there called CorporateAdmin.
and one sp is there called `usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersList` i.e used to display data from `corporateadmin` table.

I create one controller in that index action i wrote following code.

//code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ToystoreLINQDBDataContext dc = new ToystoreLINQDBDataContext();

        ISingleResult<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult> isr = dc.usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersList(1, 1);
        List<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult> myList = new List<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult>(isr);
        IEnumerable<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult> myenumrable = myList;


        return View(myList);
    }
```

and i create list view of index action.and in that code is as under.

//code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<ToystoreLINQ.Models.CorporateAdmin>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model)
   { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CorporateAdminID }) %> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CorporateAdminID })%> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CorporateAdminID })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.CorporateAdminID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.CorporateID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.UserName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LastName) %>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Email) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.IsSuperUser) %>
        </td>
               </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

now,when i run this error is occured i.e

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ToystoreLINQ.Models.usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ToystoreLINQ.Models.CorporateAdmin]'.

Can somebody help me?

---

thanks for your quick response.

i wrote like your code but still no luck.

it gave me this error.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ToystoreLINQ.Models.usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ToystoreLINQ.Models.CorporateAdmin]'.

Is there any other option?

Comment: I made one wrong assumption I guess as to where the error is occurring. Could you provide that information as well. And what changes did you made to the code now?

Answer (score 0):

In your view you declare

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<ToystoreLINQ.Models.CorporateAdmin>>"`
```

meaning that your view will be handling an object of type `IEnumerable<ToystoreLINQ.Models.CorporateAdmin>`, but in your controller action you return an `IEnumerable<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult>`. So you probably should change what your view inherits to what your action is returning.

Have to say though that I don't have used stored procedure before in LINQtoSQL, but I think you can't cast your `usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult` object to a `Model.CorporateAdmin` object straight away, that's why you are getting the error.

But if the above is the case, you have rewritten your view and it worked you could rewrite you Index() method to

```
ToystoreLINQDBDataContext dc = new ToystoreLINQDBDataContext();

ISingleResult<usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersListResult> isr = dc.usp_CorporateAdmins_ActiveUsersList(1, 1);
return View(isr.ToList());
```